# Multiple tkinter forms?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I have a GUI that I created with python and `tkinter`.

My code looks something like:

```
from Tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

master = Tk()

def f1():
    print "Change to form A"

def f2():
    print "Change to form B"

title = Label(text="Swithing Menus or Forms")
title.grid(row=0, column=1)

blank = Label(text="\n")
blank.grid(row=1, column=1)


b = Button(master, text="Submenu A", command=f1)
b.grid(row=2, column=1)

b2 = Button(master, text="Submenu B", command=f2)
b2.grid(row=2, column=2)
mainloop()
```

Buttons in the GUI allow me to call functions on click.

I know it is possible to make components inactive, but is it possible to pull up another form upon clicking a button?

Make all components disappear and bring up new ones?

Comment: Do you mean destroy all widgets and create new ones in the same tk window?

Comment: Yes to destroy all widgets but keep the window open. essentially a submit of the first "form" bringing up the second group of widgets

Answer (score 1):

personally to do this I would build each form inside a frame, that way to change forms would be as simple as:
(using pack)

```
frame1.pack_forget()
frame2.pack()
```

(using grid)

```
frame1.grid_forget()
frame2.grid()
```

and if it was to be a one way thing (ie you cannot reload the first form)
then you can call:

```
frame.destroy()
```

James

Comment: You could also lift one over the other using `frame1.lift(frame2)` (lift frame1 over frame2) or `frame1.lower(frame2)` (lower frame 1 under frame2)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, firstly James has given a good answer but i'd like to add a couple things:

You can use `grid.remove()` this will remember where a widget was etc. so you can `.grid()` it again and get it back with the same specs. This is probably slightly better than `pack/grid.forget()` as they 'forget' about the widget.

Also to answer the lower part of the question, yes you can bring up new forms, you can create more or different widgets, more windows and even another module can be called within a function.

I think this has answered your question, but if there's anything more just ask.